# Blender > Adding Nodes to a Light Using Python

Tags: python, blender

I'm new to Python and scripting for Blender. The "copy from console" method has been working for me so far, but I've hit a wall.

I've made an add-on for Blender 2.8 that adds and positions three area lights to a scene. I'd like to add a Blackbody converter to each light, set the value to 5000, and connect it to the Emission Shader, but I keep getting errors along the lines of

> AttributeError: 'AreaLight' object has no attribute 'add_node'

with every path variation I've tried.

Here's the basic script for each light I'm using:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='AREA', radius=10, location=(5, 1.5, 5))
bpy.context.active_object.data.use_nodes = True
bpy.context.active_object.data.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeBlackbody", use_transform=True)
bpy.context.active_object.name = "Area_Right"
bpy.context.active_object.data.shape = 'RECTANGLE'
bpy.context.active_object.data.energy = 300
bpy.context.active_object.data.size = 1
bpy.context.active_object.data.size_y = 3
```

> bpy.context.active_object.data.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeBlackbody", use_transform=True)

is the line that's been blocking me for the last few weeks.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution, and OF! COURSE! it took me less than 20 mins of googling. ‍♀️

Here's the solution:

```
light   = bpy.context.active_object.data
nodes   = light.node_tree.nodes
node_bb = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeBlackbody")
node_bb.inputs[0].default_value = 5000
node_bb.location = -200,300
node_ox = nodes.get('Emission')
links   = light.node_tree.links
link    = links.new(node_bb.outputs[0], node_ox.inputs[0])`
```

I tweaked code from these two posts:

[Control Cycles material nodes and material properties in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python)

[Add Nodes to Material with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/add-nodes-to-material-with-python)

If you'd like to use the script, or review it and suggest improvements, I've posted version 1.2 of the Addon to Github:

[Blender QLE](https://github.com/don1138/blender-qle)